# uncheck all grouped checkboxes or radio buttons in a list

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox

I'm trying to uncheck all checked checkboxes or radio buttons for in that grouped list, by a checkbox itself.

For a better understanding see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XWQcZ/47/

The 'Reset' checkbox unchecks all children as soon as it's selected, or vice versa.

The problem might be in this line, because it's not getting the right children:

```
 var group = $checkbox.parents('option-set').attr('data-group');
```

I got it working on the first checkboxes that are not in a list. However as soon as I put the checkboxes in the list;

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

the reset button is not working anymore.. not sure why. Thereby the radio buttons are not working properly yet.

It must be quit easy, but how to get this work properly? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Changed the fiddle. Added the values that are filtered for a better overview. However the radio buttons do not work properly yet, because it keeps the unchecked values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the 'option-set' is a class so it must be refered as a class. Just put a dot on the beginning, like:

```
var group = $checkbox.parents('.option-set').attr('data-group');
```

But the main problem is in this line:

```
$checkbox.siblings( selector ).removeAttr('checked');
```

The siblings of your checkboxes change when you put it between ul li tags. So this line should probably be:

```
$(".option-set[data-group='"+group+"'] "+selector).not($checkbox).removeAttr('checked');
```

The "not($checkbox)" filter excludes the current item itself from the list.
I think this is enough for your code to work.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed this is the solution. However, could you please have another look at this fiddle again (http://jsfiddle.net/XWQcZ/62/).. How would I make it so, that the values are changing instead of adding up at the radio buttons? The values are visible as soon as something is selected. So in other words; there can only be one value visible from the radio buttons. Thanks!

Comment: This is because you are handling radiobuttons as checkboxes. So, in line 87 you have to test if the current item is a radio and set the value of group as a unique. I´ve updated the fiddle. Take a look. (http://jsfiddle.net/QjfdF/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was working on it and I was near at the solution I see. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Give each list a unique id, but also give them all the same class

```
<ul id="group1" class="resettable">
    <li><input type="checkbox" ... ></li>
...
</ul>

<ul id="group2" class="resetable">
    <li><input type="checkbox" ... </li>
</ul>
```

give your "all" checkboxes a unique id:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="reset" ...>    
<input type="checkbox" id="brand1" ...>
```

in your jQuery, you need to add a a handler to the click event of your "all" check boxes.

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    // will uncheck all checkboxes in a <ul class="resetable">
    $('.resetable').children().prop('checked', false);

});



$('#brand1').click(function(){
//will select all check boxes in your <ul id="group1">
    $('#group1').children(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. However I'm not sure if this is the solution. Because it's not unchecking the Reset if another item is selected. Please look at the first checkboxes, it works properly there with the following code:

 `var isAll = $checkbox.hasClass('all');
   if ( isAll ) {
    delete filters[ group ];
    if ( !checkbox.checked ) {
      checkbox.checked = 'checked';
    }
  }`

So this must also work on the <li> items somehow..